# Referencing a variable in the main function - Java

Tags: java, function, variables

I have written a simple summation function where I add up values of an array. I need to reference the values of the array (which is within the main class) in my function. My code looks like this:

```
public class myClass {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
int[] myArray = {0,1,2,3,4};
//Some random operations
}
public static int sum(int low,int up)  {
    int sum;
        for (int k=low; k<=up; k++) {
                sum +=myArray[k]; }
        return sum;     
   }    
}
```

However I get the error "myArray cannot be resolved to a type". Why is this error occurring? How may I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think **D[ ]** refers to ? Have you declared such an array ?

Comment: Given a message "D cannot be resolved to a type", doesn't make sense to find the `D` in your code on the line the error message indicates, and to figure out what it is?

Comment: Oh I need to edit the question. myArray and D are actually the same array, I forgot to change it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Variables have scope. If you want to access the array referenced by `main`'s local variable `myArray` in a different method, you're going to have to pass a reference to it. See also [Oracle's tutorial on Java variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html): *" local variables are only visible to the methods in which they are declared; they are not accessible from the rest of the class."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because you declared `myArray` in a different **scope**. You declared `myArray` in the main method, therefore it cannot be accessed directly within the `sum` method. What you could do is declare it as a static variable in your class `myClass`. Declaring the variable in a static context will allow it to be accessed throughout the entire class. It would look something like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static int[] myArray = {5, 2, 6, 82};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sum(0, 3));
    }

    public static int sum(int low, int high) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
            sum += myArray[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`myArray` is currently local to the `main` method. You could pass the array to your `sum` method. Something like,

```
public static int sum(int[] myArray, int low, int up)  {
    int sum = 0; // <-- start at `0`.
    for (int k=low; k<=up; k++) {
        sum +=myArray[k]; 
    }
    return sum;    
}
```

Then you can pass `myArray` as the first argument when you call `sum`.

Comment: I need to use myArray in my main method too. Would this option still work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the array `myArray` like a paramater like this:

```
  public static int sum(int[] myArray, int low,int up)  {
       int sum=0;
    for (int k=low; k<=up; k++) {
            sum +=myArray[k]; }
    return sum;     
    }
```

In main method you can invock the method like this:

```
   int low=value1,up= value2;
   sum(myArray, value1,value2)
```